# Is there a list of CiviCRM shortcodes for Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Is there some list of shortcodes and shortcode modifiers for CiviCRM with Wordpress?

I have put a Civi Profile on a WP page, but I am hoping to hide its title and just use the form fields, but I can't find any documentation on whether this is possible or not.

Answer (score 10):

Going by the [shortcode function](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-wordpress/blob/master/includes/civicrm.shortcodes.php#L560), there are five possible ways to use the shortcode.

Technically there's only one shortcode used (`[civicrm]`) but it uses the `component` attribute to switch between different content.

The five possible components are:

- **Contribution**: `[civicrm component="contribution" id="x"]`

  shows a contribution page specified by the `id` attribute.
- **Event**: `[civicrm component="event" action="register" id="x"]` and `[civicrm component="event" action="info" id="x"]`

  shows either a registration or information page for the event specified by the `id` attribute.
- **User dashboard**: `[civicrm component="user-dashboard"]`

  shows the current user's dashboard page
- **Profile**: `[civicrm component="profile" mode="y" gid="x"]`

  shows a page for displaying a user's profile. This can be one of 4 modes - edit, view, create or search. The default is create. The `gid` attribute selects which profile group is displayed.
- **Petition**: `[civicrm component="petition" id="x"]`

  displays a petition form specified by the `id` attribute.

In addition, any of these can specify a `hijack` option and they will replace all other content on that page rather than being display inline. This looks like `hijack="1"`. A `force` attribute is mentioned in the code but I'm not clear what it does.

force=1 means it will display the table, force=0 means it will display the search box for the table and you will see the results of the search for the table after you search

Comment: More details are available in the SysAdmin Guide: https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/integration/wordpress/#using-shortcodes-to-publish-civicrm-content-in-wordpress